# Worley noise generator in 2.79?

Tags: procedural

2.8 has something I'm not investigating yet, but did anyone make an Add-on compatible with 2.79 that generated the Worley texture specifically for Materials?

Comment: Is there a difference between Worley noise and a  Voronoi texture, which is provided? (Excuse my ignorance, I've been trying to check, but it isn't clear to me, yet)

Comment: I can't get mathematical about what the difference is, but yes. :) The Worley is a variation or iteration of Voronoi - a lot of diagrams label Worley as f2 but that's not helping me Node it into existence. Voronoi breaks down to spheres around points, Worley generates linear gradients so a displacement might cast something like little funky pyramids instead of styrofoam-like shapes.